# How can I only permit that a specific string is only one time in my file

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

```
 def wordfill(word, size):
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:
        result = ' ' * int((size - len(word))/2) + word + ' ' * int((size - len(word))/2)
    else:
        result = ' ' * int((size - len(word))/2) + word + ' ' * int((size - len(word))/2) + ' '
    return result

def registermaterial():
    print('REGISTER OF MATERIAL ')
    fh_w = open("AQUESTO.txt","a+")
    name = input('Enter the name of the material: ')
    cantity = input('Enter the name of the material : ')
    str_0 = wordfill(nombre, 30).lower()
    str_1 = wordfill(cantidad, 13)

    fh_w.write('|{}|\t{}\n'.format(str_0, str_1)
```

So I have this table on a file:

---

```
name     |  cantity
gun      |     8
granade  |    12
bullets  |    8237
```

the code will always add things to the list and I want that the code only add if there is no other material with the name on the list

when uses this program:

```
name: gun 
cantity: 54
```

the table will be like this:

---

```
name     |  cantity
gun      |     8
granade  |    12
bullets  |    8237
gun      |     54
```

I don't want it add to the table because there is another object with that name. I want it like this

---

```
name     |  cantity
gun      |     8
granade  |    12
bullets  |    8237
```

and that send a message that the material from was already in the file

Comment: Why doesn't your "table on a file" follow the format of `fh_w.write('|{}|\t{}\n'.format(str_0, str_1)`?  Note the leading `|`.

Comment: because I dont know how to put my original table in the question, and I dont want to put a photo